# An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in Encrypt.exe

Tags: vb.net, encryption, visual-studio-2015

```
    Dim word As String = TextBox3.Text
    Dim letter As Char = ""
    Dim place As Integer = 0
    Dim placeLetter As String = ""
    Dim minus As Integer = 0
    Dim minusLetter As String = ""

    placeLetter = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(word, 1)
    place = SPInvert(placeLetter) 'turns the letter in to a number. eg - a = 1 , b = 2 
    minusLetter = word.Chars(place)
    minus = SPInvert(minusLetter) 'turns the letter in to a number. eg - a = 1 , b = 2  ' Error is here
```

'Under here is the function.

Function SPInvert(ByVal RAND As String) As Integer

```
    Dim cl As String = RAND
    Dim cn As Integer = 0

    If cl = "a" Then
        cn = 1
    ElseIf cl = "b" Then
        cn = cn & 2
    ElseIf cl = "c" Then
        cn = cn & 3
    ElseIf cl = "d" Then
        cn = cn & 4
    ElseIf cl = "e" Then
        cn = cn & 5
    ElseIf cl = "f" Then
        cn = cn & 6
    ElseIf cl = "g" Then
        cn = cn & 7
    ElseIf cl = "h" Then
        cn = cn & 8
    ElseIf cl = "i" Then
        cn = cn & 9
    ElseIf cl = "j" Then
        cn = cn & 10
    ElseIf cl = "k" Then
        cn = cn & 11
    ElseIf cl = "l" Then
        cn = cn & 12
    ElseIf cl = "m" Then
        cn = cn & 13
    ElseIf cl = "n" Then
        cn = cn & 14
    ElseIf cl = "o" Then
        cn = cn & 15
    ElseIf cl = "p" Then
        cn = cn & 16
    ElseIf cl = "q" Then
        cn = cn & 17
    ElseIf cl = "r" Then
        cn = cn & 18
    ElseIf cl = "s" Then
        cn = cn & 19
    ElseIf cl = "t" Then
        cn = cn & 20
    ElseIf cl = "u" Then
        cn = cn & 21
    ElseIf cl = "v" Then
        cn = cn & 22
    ElseIf cl = "w" Then
        cn = cn & 23
    ElseIf cl = "x" Then
        cn = cn & 24
    ElseIf cl = "y" Then
        cn = cn & 25
    ElseIf cl = "z" Then
        cn = cn & 26
    End If
    Return cn
End Function
```

When this code block is run, it fails and gives me this error:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in Encrypt.exe  Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: Can you post the value of `word`?..did you check somewhere if `word` is `null` or `empty`?

Comment: Assuming that `SPInvert` handles the letters a-z, `word` would need to be at least 27 character long in order to handle the letter "z" (=26).

Comment: This is not enough code to reproduce the problem. Please edit your question to add more code, and also tell us on what line the error occurred. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ive added more code.

Comment: Where it says cn = cn & x it is just something that i was using but i changed it and it doesn't really affect the code